# Filter SQL elements with adjacent ID

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-models

I don't really know how to properly state this question in the title.

Suppose I have a table `Word` like the following:

```
| id  | text   |
| --- | ---    |
|  0  | Hello  |
|  1  | Adam   |
|  2  | Hello  |
|  3  | Max    |
|  4  | foo    |
|  5  | bar    |
```

Is it possible to query this table based on `text` and receive the objects whose primary key (id) is exactly one off?

So, if I do

```
Word.objects.filter(text='Hello')
```

I get a `QuerySet` containing the rows

```
| id  | text   |
| --- | ---    |
|  0  | Hello  |
|  2  | Hello  |
```

but I want the rows

```
| id  | text   |
| --- | ---    |
|  1  | Adam   |
|  3  | Max    |
```

I guess I could do

```
word_ids = Word.objects.filter(text='Hello').values_list('id', flat=True)
word_ids = [w_id + 1 for w_id in word_ids]  # or use a numpy array for this
Word.objects.filter(id__in=word_ids)
```

but that doesn't seem overly efficient. Is there a straight SQL way to do this in one call? Preferably directly using Django's QuerySets?

**EDIT:** The idea is that in fact I want to filter those words that are in the second QuerySet. Something like:

```
Word.objects.filter(text__of__previous__word='Hello', text='Max')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain Postgres you could use the `lag` window function (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html)

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    name 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        lag(name) OVER (ORDER BY id) as prev_name
    FROM test
) s
WHERE prev_name = 'Hello'
```

The `lag` function adds a column with the text of the previous row. So you can filter by this text in a subquery.

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=048cfc1fed696cdd75213c4157f6b6ab)

---

I am not really into Django but the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) means, in version 2.0 the functionality for window function has been added.

Comment: This is great, thanks! Especially the demo fiddle. Since I'm using django 1.11 for the moment I will use the raw sql statement. Could you explain to me what the `s` means? Why is that there?

Comment: In Postgres every subquery needs an alias. So I simply named the subquery "s". It's just for syntax purposes but includes no magic :)

Answer (score 1):

If by "1 off" you mean that the difference is exactly 1, then you can do:

```
select w.*
from w
where w.id in (select w2.id + 1 from words w2 where w2.text = 'Hello');
```

`lag()` is also a very reasonable solution.  This seems like a direct interpretation of your question.  If you have gaps (and the intention is `+ 1`), then `lag()` is a bit trickier.

Comment: By trickier you mean that `lag` will still return the "next" pk even if it is not `+1`?

Comment: @MoRe . . . Yes.  So it depends if "1 off" literally means that the difference between the `id`s is 1.  Or if "1 off" is a little more figurative and simply means the previous `id`.